# Need help with PHP array

Tags: php

Can anybody help me out, I'm stuck, don't know how to write a php nested for loop to convert into a key value array.

This is the array structure.

Needed to turn into key value array( combining JobDescription and userdetail array together)

```
array(2) {
    ["jobDescription"]=> array(5) {
        ["funeralFor"]=> string(6) "Myself"
        ["serviceType"]=> string(1) "1"
        ["religionType"]=> string(1) "2"
        ["area"]=> string(4) "2154"
        ["customerComment"]=> string(6) "fdfddf"
    }
    ["userDetail"]=> array(6) {
        ["contactEmail"]=> string(16) "fdddf@fffgfg.com"
        ["contactFirstName"]=> string(6) "fddfdf"
        ["contactLastName"]=> string(6) "fddffd"
        ["contactPhoneNumber"]=> string(10) "0420988191"
        ["signup"]=> array(2) {
            ["id"]=> string(32) "8048f0f7106c336e1a8825d1d3bec902"
            ["input"]=> string(3) "k5m"
        }
        ["agreement"]=> string(1) "1"
    }
}
```

Thanks so much in advance

Comment: Please post a formatted version of the array (if you've copied it from a web browser, use "view source" in the browser to preserve whitespaces).

Comment: You have another array within userDetail for signup. Should that remain as an array or should it also be combined into the single array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two arrays stored in an array. You want the values of both arrays under one array instead of two subarrays?

```
$newArray = array_merge($array['jobDescription'], $array['userDetail']);
```

Comment: Had the same suggestion with [array_merge()](http://php.net/array_merge), probably that's what he looks for.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [`array_merge`](http://php.net/array_merge), which merges two arrays together:

```
$new_arr = array_merge($arr['jobDescription'], $arr['userDetail']);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array_merge($bigArray['jobDescription'], $bigArray['userDetail']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to loop once. No need for nesting. This solution covers where you have an undefined number of arrays to combine. Otherwise, you can use `array_merge` as suggested by Dickie

```
$allValues = array();

if(count($mainArray) > 0)
{
    foreach($mainArray as $arr)
    {
        $allValues += $arr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/array_merge) function can create an array from multiple arrays. In your example, it works this way:

```
$yours = array(...);
$values = array_merge($yours["jobDescription"], $yours["userDetail"]);
```